# Why is the name NBT (Named Binary Tag) used?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the meaning of "named binary tag"?

What about NBT is binary?

Comment: binary data here just refers to data that is not Unicode text/human-readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word binary is in the name because it stores binary data, as opposed to text data. See [the NBT specification](http://web.archive.org/web/20110723210920/http://www.minecraft.net/docs/NBT.txt):

> NBT (Named Binary Tag) is a tag based **binary format** designed to carry large amounts of **binary data** with smaller amounts of additional data.

Comment: Binary data here just refers to data that is not Unicode text/human-readable

Comment: @RayWu it is utf-8 for strings for example

Comment: @theonlygusti yes but it stores many things in non-text formats, like ints and bytes and floats

Comment: @RayWu everything on a computer is binary. I guess the name kind of makes sense though.

Comment: @RayWu it depends on the situation. Yes, everything under it all is binary, I.e. 1s and 0s. However in programming logic it is one of two things. A "Named Binary Tag" can be `true` or `false`, but nothing else. Therefore it is "binary"

Comment: @Ben I did not decide the name. I'm telling you what Notch thought while designing it

Comment: I think Ben meant to tag theonlygusti :)